# Outlook Advanced Search on property GlobalAppointmentID

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, advanced-search

Alright so I'm needing some help here. I working with Outlook 2007 PIA (Outlook add-in) and using the advanced search. I'm trying to write a DASL filter for the AppointmentItem property GlobalAppointmentID but I cannot seem to find the correct namespace to use in the filter.

I've tried urn:schemas:calendar:uid and I do not get any results when searching on the first appointment in the default calendar list. The MSDN documentation states that this is a mapi property but I am unfamiliar with mapi so at the moment I do not know how to even find it in the msdn that way (I tried and ended up way over my head).

I know there is a work around to go to the default folder and iterate through the collection to find the object that I need but I consider that too inefficient (I'm using it at the moment but want to improve it).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OOM will not let you search for `GlobalAppointmentId` (or any other `PT_BINARY` property) in `Items.Find`/FindNext/`Restrict`. The only workaround is to either loop through all item in the Calendar folder (extremely inefficient) or search using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - any language, its version of `RDOFolder`.[Items](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`Find` allows to search on `GlobalAppointmentId` or any other binary property)

Answer (score 0):

Not every property can be used in a filter string for `Items.Restrict`, `Table.Restrict` or `Application.AdvancedSearch` methods. For both Jet and DASL queries, you cannot restrict on a binary property such as `EntryID` or `GlobalAppointmentID`. Also you cannot restrict or search for computed properties.

Anyway, you may find the [Chapter 11: Searching Outlook Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc513841%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) helpful.